# Pybind11 How to pass an n-dimentional numpy array from python -> c++

Tags: python, c++, numpy-ndarray, pybind11

I have a numpy array of numpy arrays of floats that I wish to pass to a c++ function that will read and modify the data as if it were a std::vector.
I am struggling to figure out how to do this.
What would the c++ argument type be for:

`np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]], dtype=float)`

This type declaration: `py::array_t<py::array_t<float>>`

produces this error: `Attempt to use a non-POD or unimplemented POD type as a numpy dtype`

and I can't see to get this type declaration to work: `py:array`

I have searched through documentation, github issues and examples I can find online but have not found anything that works or that I can make sense of, if anyone could help me with this, it would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull in the Eigen library on the C++ side and use that for your matrix operations.  `std::vector` is not a good abstraction for 2d matrices... either  you have to write your own 2d indexing into a 1d vector, or you need something silly like `std::vector<std::vector<>>`, which performs very badly and is ugly besides.

`pybind11` knows the type conversions to automatically convert `np.array` to `Eigen::MatrixXf`, so you should be able to write your C++ function as taking a `Eigen::MatrixXf input`, and call it as you've specified.

[This last paragraph added based on the OP's comment]

Note that this will create copies of the matrix, and if you want reference passing instead (you should), pybind11 [documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/cast/eigen.html#pass-by-reference) says that your function signature should use the Eigen Ref template type: `my_cpp_fn(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXf>)` or `my_cpp_fn(const Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXf>)`.  Done this way, no data copies should occur across the Python/C++ interface.

Comment: Thank you for the reply - that works as expected!  I assume the pass by reference approach will work the same: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/cast/eigen.html#pass-by-reference

Comment: Yes, this is a great point.  As your reference suggests, my example should have said that your C++ function should accept `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXf>` or `const Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXf>`.